# How to make a page counter in pdf in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

I working with `react-pdf` to display pdf using a link. I have completed the pdf viewer. What I want to do now is to make a pdf page counter. So that user know what page he is in.

What I have tried is to give `window` a `scroll` event which will increment the pages on specific number of scrolls. But its not working. Also I want user to enter page number in the space to navigate to that specific page.

[image]

This is how the page counter looks like. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code

Answer (score 1):

You can display page number and total number of pages like this

```
<Text render={({ pageNumber, totalPages }) => (
    `${pageNumber} / ${totalPages}`
  )} fixed />
```

se docs https://react-pdf.org/advanced

Comment: where is the Text component?

Comment: https://react-pdf.org/components#text

Answer (score -1):

use [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) module

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';
    
    function App() {
      const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(0);
      const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
    
      function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }) {
        setNumPages(numPages);
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{pageNumber} / {numPages}</p>
          <Document
            file="somefile.pdf"
            onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
            <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
          </Document>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: I have tried this but not work.